# method takes too long

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle, resultset

I wrote a method that gathers data from an Oracle server, formats and encrypts the data then inserts it into a MS SQL server.  The method moves about 60000 records and takes a bit long and is a little sloppy.  Can anyone see places to clean it up and make it faster?

2 of the areas that I see might need improvements are when the result set is being added the the List.  And when the List is being inserted 1000 rows at a time into the MS SQL table.

Here is the code:

```
public static void get_random_selection(Connection ora_conn, Connection sql_conn) throws Exception, SQLException{

    Statement sql_stmt = sql_conn.createStatement();
    Statement ora_stmt = ora_conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet sql_rs = null;
    ResultSet ora_rs = null;

    //Select the max QUARTER from RANDOM_SELECTION in MS SQL
    sql_rs = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");

    sql_rs.next();
    int max_from_mssql = sql_rs.getInt(1);

    ora_rs = ora_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");

    ora_rs.next();
    int max_from_oracle = ora_rs.getInt(1);

    //If the max_from_oracle is larger than max_from_mssql than the AL's and RL's in Oracle
    //are fresher and need to be moved to MS SQL
    //if (max_from_oracle > max_from_mssql){
    if(1==1){

        System.out.println("The RANDOM_SELECTION table in Oracle is more up to date than the RANDOM_SELECTION table in MS SQL.");

        System.out.println("Retrieving RANDOM_SELECTION data from Oracle.");

        //select items from RANDOM_SELECTION and DROPPER_CITY_BRK_2 that need to be moved
        ora_rs = ora_stmt.executeQuery("select distinct(random_selection.randnum), " 
                            + "random_selection.quarter, " 
                            + "random_selection.ozip3, "
                            + "random_selection.boxid, " 
                            + "random_selection.boxaddr, " 
                            + "random_selection.locdesc, " 
                            + "random_selection.loccity, " 
                            + "random_selection.lastmf, "
                            + "random_selection.lastsat, "
                            + "random_selection.boxtype, "
                            + "random_selection.svcclas, "
                            + "random_selection.dropzip5, "
                            + "random_selection.dropper_id "
                      + "from random_selection "
                      + "where random_selection.dropper_id is not null "
                      + "and random_selection.quarter = " + max_from_oracle + " "

                  + "union "

                      + "select distinct(random_selection.randnum), "
                            + "random_selection.quarter, " 
                            + "random_selection.ozip3, "
                            + "random_selection.boxid, " 
                            + "random_selection.boxaddr, " 
                            + "random_selection.locdesc, " 
                            + "random_selection.loccity, " 
                            + "random_selection.lastmf, "
                            + "random_selection.lastsat, "
                            + "random_selection.boxtype, "
                            + "random_selection.svcclas, "
                            + "random_selection.dropzip5, "
                            + "dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id "
                      + "from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2, dropper "
                      + "where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 "
                      + "and dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id "
                      + "and dropper.active = 1 "
                      + "and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002 "
                      + "and random_selection.quarter = " + max_from_oracle + " "
                      + "and random_selection.dropper_id is null");

        System.out.println("Retrieved RANDOM_SELECTION data from Oracle.");

        List<String[]> random_selection = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        System.out.println("Assigning ResultSet to List.");

        while (ora_rs.next()){
            random_selection.add(new String[]{
                ora_rs.getString("RANDNUM"),
                ora_rs.getString("QUARTER"),
                ora_rs.getString("OZIP3"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXID"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXADDR").replace("'"," "),
                ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC") == null ? ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC") : ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC").replace("'",""),
                ora_rs.getString("LOCCITY").replace("'", " "),
                ora_rs.getString("LASTMF"),
                ora_rs.getString("LASTSAT").equals("11:58pm") ? "null": ora_rs.getString("LASTSAT"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXTYPE"),
                ora_rs.getString("SVCCLAS"),
                ora_rs.getString("DROPZIP5"),
                ora_rs.getString("DROPPER_ID")});

            System.out.println(ora_rs.getRow());
        }

        System.out.println("Finished assigning ResultSet to List.");

        //leading statement for the following loop
        String query = "insert into random_selection "
                  + "(RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";

        int jj = 0;

        //loop through random_selection_array creating an INSERT statement to insert 999 entries at a time
        //this is done to speed up the process
        for(int ii = 0;ii<random_selection.size();ii++){

            String[] array_holder = random_selection.get(ii);

            query = query
                  + "("
                  + "'"+array_holder[0]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[1]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[2]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[3]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[4]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[5]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[6]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[7]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[8]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[9]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[10]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[11]+"',"
                  + "'"+new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypt(array_holder[12]))+"'),";

            //every 999 iterations enter here
            if (jj > 998){
                //add |%| to the end of the string so that you can remove the final ','
                query = query+"|%|"; 
                query = query.replace(",|%|","");

                System.out.println(query);

                //sql_stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                query = "insert into random_selection (RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";
                jj = 0;
            }
            jj++;

            //the last few entries will be added one at a time to prevent nulls records from being inserted
            if (ii > (random_selection.size() / 999) * 999){
                //add |%| to the end of the string so that you can remove the final ','
                query = query+"|%|";
                query = query.replace(",|%|","");

                System.out.println(query);

                //sql_stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                query = "insert into random_selection (RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The client wants to refrain from any open connections between the 2 servers.

Comment: Probably should be asked here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this method does way too much. it's a pain to follow and could use some refactoring. btw, can you add a linked server in MS sql server to to do all of this in the database?

Comment: @Mike - Does the code absolutely need to be in Java?  It's generally going to be pretty expensive to read all the data from the source database over the network, process it, then write it all back out over the network.  Architecturally, it would be more efficient if the data was sent directly from one database to another.  For example, you could create a database link in Oracle that points to SQL Server and have an Oracle stored procedure write the data directly to SQL Server without the intermediate hop at the application server.

Comment: @JustinCave The client does not want any open connections between the 2 servers.

Comment: Use PreparedStatement instead of Statement.

Comment: Concatenating strings is inefficient so use a StringBuffer to concatenate all your query values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is likely with the large number of inserts being done on the MS SQL server. It's not very efficient to do that.

The correct way to transfer data between two databases (without linking) is to [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) rows in and out.

First, keep in mind that I don't have any experience with BCP outside of sybase.

1. Figure out how to get your data into MS bcp format. There are a few ways this could be done. I would try to create a view with all required in the oracle db and bcp out from there, but that may not be possible with the encrypt() stuff.
2. bcp in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of guessing, you should actually write out to the console how long it ACTUALLY takes for each of those areas that you think are slow. :) Second, you should use a prepared statement and use addBatch and executeBatch. In C# I would use SqlBulkCopy, but I don't think Java has a class like that, so you should try addBatch and executeBatch. If that is still too slow, then I would use BULK INSERT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx